# Add multiple CSS File without override standard tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I need to include in my .html some CSS library ( as materialize.css ) but I don't want that they override standard tags  as `<li>`, I need to only use some classes, there is a way to use them only when I need?

Comment: edit the css code of materialize css and remove what you dont need

Answer (score 0):

Don't include full file materialize.css. just put required class in it which you want to use.

OR

Just copy class from materialize.css which you need to use in to your main CSS file